# access active assembly resources

Tags: c#, resources, .net-assembly

I am trying to dynamically load images from the Resources folder but for some reason `GetManifestResourceStream` returns null. This is what I wrote:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly asm;
asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Properties.Resources.Image.png"));
```

I've tried every method I found here, but it doesn't work. The path is correct, the file is there. I need to do this dynamically because depending on user permissions, different assemblies will be loaded. So basically I need two things:

1. Get a list with all the assemblies that were loaded
2. Load an image corresponding to the loaded assembly into a Bitmap

How can this be done?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Both versions (GetExecutingAssembly and GetCallingAssembly) work if you set the file's build action property to Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means the resource name is incorrect. Load the assembly in ildasm, look at the manifest for ".mresources" sections and find the one you want to load.

If not, the call to [GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) returns the assembly containing the code currently executing, which may be different to the DLL that contains the resource.  Use [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) to load it from a separate DLL instead.

To answer your questions above:

> 1. Get a list with all the assemblies that were loaded

Use the [AppDomain.GetAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) method, for example:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

> 1. Load an image corresponding to the loaded assembly into a Bitmap

Iterate through the assemblies looking for the resource using GetManifestResourceStream.

Comment: According to ildasm the resource name is correct. Can it be something else?